# Max retries exceeded with url (GTM server side)

Tags: python, python-3.x, https, port, google-tag-manager

I have setup GTM server side following this guide: https://aws-solutions-library-samples.github.io/advertising-marketing/using-google-tag-manager-for-server-side-website-analytics-on-aws.html

Now, when I send local curl requests to my GTM server URL, I get an OK response. But I want to write a script that sends around 50k POST request per minute (same payload, same URL) for a specified time period (for example 1 full minute).

I tried this:

```
import requests
import concurrent.futures
import time

url = "https://xxx/com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow/enriched"

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
...
events_per_minute_target = 50000

# Calculate the total number of events to send
total_events = events_per_minute_target * 1  # 1 min

start_time = time.time()

def send_request(_):
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)

        # Check if the request was successful (status code 2xx)
        if response.ok:
            print(f"Request successful. Response: {response.text}")
        else:
            print(f"Request failed. Status code: {response.status_code}, Response: {response.text}")

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=events_per_minute_target) as executor:
    # Submit tasks to the executor
    futures = [executor.submit(send_request, None) for _ in range(total_events)]

# Wait for all tasks to complete
concurrent.futures.wait(futures)

# Calculate the actual events per minute for the entire test duration
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
actual_events_per_minute = total_events / (elapsed_time / 60)

print(f"Load test completed. Actual events per minute: {actual_events_per_minute:.2f}")
```

previously, the script was running and logging an OK response. However, now when I try to run the same script, I get this:

```
An error occurred: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xx', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /com.snowplowanalytics.snowplow/enriched (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x107832b90>: Failed to resolve 'xxx' ([Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known)"))
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Note that even when the script was running and returning OK responses, it ran for a lot longer than 1 minute (not intended) and I eventually had to kill the process using Cntrl + C